# Как преобразовать логические False, True в 1, 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть ли функция для преобразования булевых значений в числовые?

Только мне нужно, чтобы `False -> 1`, а `True -> 0`.
В принципе можно и `replace` использовать, но хочется найти более красивый способ.

Comment: В Питоне `True == 1 and False == 0` и `isinstance(True, int)` отличие при печати (преобразовании в строку) в основном.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.choice([True, False], 10)})

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
     col
0  False
1   True
2   True
3  False
4  False
5   True
6  False
7  False
8   True
9  False
```

решение:

```
In [22]: df['col'] = (-df['col']).astype(np.int8)

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   col
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    0
9    1

In [24]: df.dtypes
Out[24]:
col    int8
dtype: object
```

альтернативный вариант:

```
In [27]: df['col'] = (~df['col']).astype(np.uint8)

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   col
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    0
9    1
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @DenisNovik, был рад помочь :)

Comment: А минус в `-df['col']` обязательный для этой магии? :)

Comment: @gil9red: автор хочет обратить False/True: `False -> 1`, `True -> 0` (обычно обратные значения). Хотя `~` более читаема была бы здесь, чем `-`.

Comment: возможно без знака тип тут подошёл бы: `np.uint8`

Comment: @jfs, да, `uint8` здесь тоже подойдет...